# Dropwizard 0.8.2 Admin Port is not working

Tags: java, dropwizard

Does any one know, if there are currently any known bugs for DW admin port?At the moment I can not use admin port, because it it not available.

```
INFO  [2015-08-14 10:59:10,428] [] [] [main]: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:?:?- Started i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@154bd49b{/,null,AVAILABLE}
INFO  [2015-08-14 10:59:10,432] [] [] [main]: io.dropwizard.setup.AdminEnvironment:?:?- tasks = 

    POST    /tasks/log-level (io.dropwizard.servlets.tasks.LogConfigurationTask)
    POST    /tasks/gc (io.dropwizard.servlets.tasks.GarbageCollectionTask)

INFO  [2015-08-14 10:59:10,437] [] [] [main]: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:?:?- Started i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@1a87b51{/,null,AVAILABLE}
INFO  [2015-08-14 10:59:10,463] [] [] [main]: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:?:?- Started application@6c2d4cc6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:80}
INFO  [2015-08-14 10:59:10,472] [] [] [main]: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:?:?- Started admin@30865a90{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFO  [2015-08-14 10:59:10,472] [] [] [main]: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:?:?- Started @3531ms
```

Try doing POST@localhost:8080/tasks/log-level or @../tasks/gc or @localhost:8080/healtcheck does not workn but it is finished very fast if server is not running and takes some time if server is running.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here? I tried many different port, so this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was, that in config there was adminMaxThreads set to 2 by ITO. Set this to 8 solves the problem.

Update:
With DW 0.8.4 I found another strange admin not working problem. The above does not help, but commenting out solves the probem:

```
server:
  rootPath: '/rest/*'
  requestLog:
    timeZone: UTC
    appenders:
     - type: console
       threshold: DEBUG
     - type: file
       currentLogFilename: ./logs/access.log
       threshold: ALL
       archive: true
       archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/access.%d.log.gz
       archivedFileCount: 14
  #adminMinThreads: 12
  #adminMaxThreads: 16
  #maxThreads: 1024
  #minThreads: 12
  #maxQueuedRequests: 1024
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 52131
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 52132
```

I dont know whats wrong with this config, if I remove the commented out lines, but above one works.